# NullPointerException while retrieving data from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to set my TextView to the current user username but i'm getting this error:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
```

and this is how i'm retrieving the username:

```
mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

               String name= dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue().toString();
               username.setText(name);

           }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.w("ProfileActivity", "load:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());

        }
    });
```

this is my user node:

[image: users firebase]

this:

```
 mCurrUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
 Uid = mCurrUser.getUid();
 mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(Uid);
```

Comment: Guessing `dataSnapshot.child("username")` is null

Comment: Or more likely the `getValue()` returns null

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: how can I fix this

Comment: Why are you calling `toString()` in the first place? It's already a string. If you weren't doing that yuo wouldn't have got this NPE, you would just have called `username.setText(null)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue()` is returning null, which means that there is no child called "username" at the location of your query.  From your comments, it sounds like you're building `mDatabase` like this:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(Uid);
```

The problem here is that your code is accessing "Users" with a capital U, but the data you're showing in the database exists at "users" with a lowercase u.

Comment: `mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(Uid);`

Comment: `Uid` is probably not what you expect.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: What exactly is `Uid`? Log its value. Does it have the value you expect for the query?

Comment: yeah it's 9ebbbm1B9gY21JHSucA9iCFDAw73 and i'm logged as 'admin' which matches the uid

Comment: You should be accessing "users" with a lowercase u, instead of "Users" with a capital U.

Comment: yeah you're right ! thank you so much !!!!